# Stack to deep using Merge Sort

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to implement merge sort on my own using recursion.

```
def merge_sort(a,i,j)
  if i < j 
    merge_sort(a,i,j/2)
    merge_sort(a,j/2+1,j)
    merge(a,i,j/2,j/2+1,j)
  end
end

def merge(a,i,j,k,l)
  # No implementation yet
end
```

The problem is my implementation results in the stack going too deep. I shouldn't be getting this error message for such a small array. The array I'm trying to sort is just five elements.

```
b = [5,4,3,2,1]
p merge_sort(b,0,b.size - 1) # => results in 'stack to deep' message
```

Comment: First step is debugging. `p [ a, i, j ]` as a first line would probably be *very* illuminating. My money is on an off-by-one error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a step in the right direction that's made a bit more Ruby-like in how it's more forgiving, plus as a bonus has actual names instead of mathematical shorthand:

```
def merge_sort(arr,from = nil,to = nil)
  from ||= 0
  to ||= arr.length

  if (from < to)
    part = from + (to - from) / 2

    merge_sort(arr, from, part)
    merge_sort(arr, part + 1, to)

    merge(arr, from,part, part+1, to)
  end
end

def merge(a,from,j,k,l)
  # No implementation yet
end

b = [5,4,3,2,1]
merge_sort(b)
```

The mistake came about from not properly defining the partition point. In the original code for an array of length 5 the cut point would be 2, and when that's further divided, the cut point is 2/1 or 1, not 2+(5-3)/2 or 3 as it should be. From there it all went crazy because it was doing the math wrong and kept calling itself for no reason.

Comment: `# No frommplementatfromon yet` Did someone try to parse Ruby with Regexp? ;-)

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using `def merge_sort(arr, from = 0, to = arr.length)`?

Comment: @JörgWMittag It's just a personal aversion to over-complicating defaults. That's certainly a valid approach.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was my midpoint formula was wrong and was throwing the recursion into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was my mid-point formula was off throwing the recursion into an infinite loop recursing until the stack overflowed. Instead of

> j / 2 + 1

It should have been

> (i+j) / 2 + 1

tadman got the formula right in his re-versioning